# Why my golang lock free queue always stuck there?

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
    "sync"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    MAX_DATA_SIZE = 100
)

// lock free queue
type Queue struct {
    head unsafe.Pointer
    tail unsafe.Pointer
}
// one node in queue
type Node struct {
    val interface{}
    next unsafe.Pointer
}
// queue functions
func (self *Queue) enQueue(val interface{}) {
    newValue := unsafe.Pointer(&Node{val: val, next: nil})
    var tail,next unsafe.Pointer
    for {
        tail = self.tail
        next = ((*Node)(tail)).next
        if next != nil {
            atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&(self.tail), tail, next)
        }else if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&((*Node)(tail).next), nil, newValue){
            break
        }
    }
}

func (self *Queue) deQueue() (val interface{}, success bool){
    var head,tail,next unsafe.Pointer
    for {
        head = self.head
        tail = self.tail
        next = ((*Node)(head)).next
        if head == tail {
            if next == nil {
                return nil, false
            }else {
                atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&(self.tail), tail, next)
            }
        }else {
            val = ((*Node)(next)).val
            if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&(self.head), head, next) {
                return val, true
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(20)
    queue := new(Queue)
    queue.head = unsafe.Pointer(new(Node))
    queue.tail = queue.head

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < MAX_DATA_SIZE; j++ {
                t := time.Now()
                queue.enQueue(t)
                fmt.Println("enq = ", t)
            }
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            ok := false
            var val interface{}
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < MAX_DATA_SIZE; j++ {
                val,ok = queue.deQueue()
                for !ok {
                    val,ok = queue.deQueue()
                }
                fmt.Println("deq = ",val)
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

The problem is, sometimes the code runs ok, but sometimes it fails and just gets stuck with no response.

Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: I only get stuck when GOMAXPROCS is >1, since some people will ask.

Comment: do you get stuck everytime GOMAXPROCS is >1 or only some of the time?

Comment: Is there a reason a buffered channel or other higher level structure is not appropriate for your application? There are ways to make a queue of this nature with no upper limit on size with a couple channels and a goroutine.

Comment: @mkb I didn't set the value of GOMAXPROCS (Default is 1), but it still stuck soem of the time. My application runs too slow, so i think the lock free queue may make some speedup, will it ?

Comment: @JeremyWall I get stuck some of the time, and my runtime.GOMAXPROCS is 1.

Comment: So I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here but I suspect you could do this much much easier with some channels as mkb. Maybe if you told us what the goal is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the above re-written with channels as @mkb suggested (bar the infinite queue size).

It doesn't lock up.

I'd suggest you use channels unless you have a really good reason not to as the Go team have spend a great deal of effort making them reliable, high performance and easy to use.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    MAX_DATA_SIZE = 100
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(20)
    queue := make(chan time.Time, 10)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < MAX_DATA_SIZE; j++ {
                t := time.Now()
                queue <- t
                fmt.Println("enq = ", t)
            }
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < MAX_DATA_SIZE; j++ {
                val := <-queue
                fmt.Println("deq = ", val)
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick,channels are awesome.But here i really want to know why my code doesn't work well.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of active waiting in this code, and I strongly recommend a clean use of channel just like Nick's nice code.

However, here is my answer to the exact original question "Why is it stuck?" : there is no garantee of when each goroutine will yield to let the others execute, and most probably it will never yield when inside an infinite loop.

You can fix this by using [runtime.Gosched()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) inside each possibly-infinite for loop :

> Gosched yields the processor, allowing other goroutines to run. It
>   does not suspend the current goroutine, so execution resumes
>   automatically.

This enhanced code runs almost as fast as the original, but never hangs :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    MAX_DATA_SIZE = 100
)

// lock free queue
type Queue struct {
    head unsafe.Pointer
    tail unsafe.Pointer
}

// one node in queue
type Node struct {
    val  interface{}
    next unsafe.Pointer
}

// queue functions
func (self *Queue) enQueue(val interface{}) {
    newValue := unsafe.Pointer(&Node{val: val, next: nil})
    var tail, next unsafe.Pointer
    for {
        tail = self.tail
        next = ((*Node)(tail)).next
        if next != nil {
            atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&(self.tail), tail, next)
        } else if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&((*Node)(tail).next), nil, newValue) {
            break
        }
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}

func (self *Queue) deQueue() (val interface{}, success bool) {
    var head, tail, next unsafe.Pointer
    for {
        head = self.head
        tail = self.tail
        next = ((*Node)(head)).next
        if head == tail {
            if next == nil {
                return nil, false
            } else {
                atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&(self.tail), tail, next)
            }
        } else {
            val = ((*Node)(next)).val
            if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&(self.head), head, next) {
                return val, true
            }
        }
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(20)
    queue := new(Queue)
    queue.head = unsafe.Pointer(new(Node))
    queue.tail = queue.head

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < MAX_DATA_SIZE; j++ {
                t := time.Now()
                queue.enQueue(t)
                fmt.Println("enq = ", t)
            }
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            ok := false
            var val interface{}
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < MAX_DATA_SIZE; j++ {
                val, ok = queue.deQueue()
                for !ok {
                    val, ok = queue.deQueue()
                    runtime.Gosched()
                }
                fmt.Println("deq = ", val)
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```